# How can I retrieve the last non-zero value in a column

Tags: oracle

So this is what I see

```
Column 1 Column 2 Column 3

103.46  15-10-02    150.60
381.67  15-10-02    150.60
741.31  15-10-03    0
14.21   15-10-03    0
35.37   15-10-05    0
11.24   15-10-12    19.23
13.77   15-10-13    0
```

and I'd like to insert the previous non-zero value from column 3 wherever there is a zero in column 3

so I would see something like

```
Column 1 Column 2 Column 3

103.46  15-10-02    150.60
381.67  15-10-02    150.60
741.31  15-10-03    150.60
14.21   15-10-03    150.60
35.37   15-10-05    150.60
11.24   15-10-12    19.23
13.77   15-10-13    19.23
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What did you try sofar? And which DBMS mysql or sql-server?

Comment: Given that rows in an RDBMS represent unordered sets, which one is 'previous'  (although in this particular instance it may not matter) - and which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: I'm on oracle sql developer, and when I say 'previous' I'm referring to the previous day/date (column 2) with a associated non-zero value in column 3

I tried leading the data but since i have multiple day values it doesn't seem to be the right option here

Comment: then why do you have sql-server and mysql tagged? they are different in many ways.

Comment: they were suggested tags

Comment: lava the issue with that is what happens when you have more than one value on the previous date? it makes no sense. the "first" two rows are from the second day.. but what if one of those values are different? which one do you use? you cant go by order of entry

Comment: The values in column 3 will always be the same for each day 
--
Let me try to be clearer.
--
If there are two entries for October 02, and a value exists for column 3 on that day then the value will be the same for both entries.


I just want to be able to tell oracle to look at column 3, see that it's zero and then grab the previous non-zero value and plop it in there.
--
Generally I would use NVL or COALESE if I want to input some random string or number but this is more dynamic than that (as far as I understand)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LAST_VALUE() will do what you need:

```
with table1 as (select 103.46 col1, to_date('01/10/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') col2, 0 col3 from dual union all
                select 381.67 col1, to_date('02/10/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') col2, 150.60 col3 from dual union all
                select 741.31 col1, to_date('03/10/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') col2, 0 col3 from dual union all
                select 14.21 col1, to_date('03/10/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') col2, 0 col3 from dual union all
                select 35.37 col1, to_date('05/10/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') col2, 0 col3 from dual union all
                select 11.24 col1, to_date('12/10/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') col2, 19.23 col3 from dual union all
                select 13.77 col1, to_date('13/10/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') col2, 0 col3 from dual)
select col1,
       col2,
       nvl(last_value(decode(col3, 0, cast(null as number), col3)) ignore nulls over (order by col2, col3 desc), 0) col3
from   table1;

      COL1 COL2             COL3
---------- ---------- ----------
    103.46 01/10/2015          0
    381.67 02/10/2015      150.6
    741.31 03/10/2015      150.6
     14.21 03/10/2015      150.6
     35.37 05/10/2015      150.6
     11.24 12/10/2015      19.23
     13.77 13/10/2015      19.23
```

Comment: This is the bomb. Worked like a beaut! 

Exactly what I needed. Thank you and a 100 years of good harvests for you and your family!

Comment: I've updated the answer just to include the case where the earliest value is a 0; without the nvl around it, it would appear without a value, whereas you probably still want to return 0 in that case. Also, I cast the null in the decode to be a number, as it was converting the number column to a string, which may or may not be an issue for you. And good fortune to you and yours *{:-)

Comment: Just be carefull what last value mean, here the order is by col2, col3, no necesary the same order as data arrive at db. You should include an ID column autonumeric to make sure the order. Or use DATETIME instead of DATE

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered using a [CASE STATEMENT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm)?

```
CASE 
    WHEN Column1 <> 0 THEN Column1
    WHEN Column2 <> 0 THEN Column2
    ELSE Column3
END AS NewColumn3
```

Comment: This doesn't meet the OP's requirements at all. It doesn't reference the previous row at all.

Comment: Whoops!  I misunderstood the question.  You're right my solution doesn't work at all.